# Histogram specification using matlab for image enhancement

Tags: matlab

In histogram specification we specify the shape of the desired histogram.
For an image we should modify the histogram such that it is close to the shape of the desired histogram.
Can anyone tell me how can I do that.

Histogram equalization used histeq().
Is there any special function for histogram specification.

Comment: You mean like `J = histeq(I, hgram)` found [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/histeq.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the documentation for `histeq` you will see that it accepts an optional second argument which is the desired histogram:

> `J = histeq(I, hgram)` transformsthe intensity image I so that the histogram of the output intensity image `J` with `length(hgram)` bins approximately matches `hgram`. The vector `hgram` should contain integer counts for equally spaced bins with intensity values in the appropriate range: [0, 1] for images of class double, [0, 255] for images of class uint8, and [0, 65535] for images of class `uint16`. `histeq` automatically scales `hgram` so that `sum(hgram) = prod(size(I))`. The histogram of J will better match `hgram` when `length(hgram)` is much smaller than the number of discrete levels in I.

Comment: suppose i want the histogram to be in the shape of half sine wave. how do i do that.

Comment: @Abhilash - You would fill the vector hgram with the values of sine from zero to pi, or, `hgram(ii)=sin((ii-1)*pi/(bins-1))` where `bins` is length(hgram). This will give you values in the range [0, 1] which you will have to scale appropriately as above.